# HTML <audio> tag Can't load the audio file

Tags: html, audio

I'm sure I miss something very simple here.

In `<audio>` tag, I can't get the audio load, the result is always 'Your browser doesn't support HTML5 audio'. The link to the audio file is correct (working with `<a>` tag). tried with an online link and local link, the same result.

```
<audio src="/Users/myName/Desktop/audioFile.mp3" controls>
    <p>Your browser doesn't support HTML5 audio. Here is a
    <a href="/Users/myName/Desktop/audioFile.mp3">link to the audio</a> instead.</p>
</audio>
```

Comment: Also try absolute path (with http) to make sure if the url routing works fine.

Comment: What are your browser and its version?

Comment: @AliSheikhpour tried it, same result.

Comment: @SMAKSS chrome version 81

Comment: @DvirSadeh Did you tried other browsers as well?

Comment: @SMAKSS I've tried Safari and Opera now, same result

Comment: Does your browser start playing audio when you click on `<a>` link?

Comment: @AliSheikhpour yes

Comment: Also make sure it is not a MP4 file saved with mp3 extension

Comment: @AliSheikhpour I've tried a few different files to make sure this is not the problem